# Creating a kafka consumer using spark streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have started kafka, created a topic and a producer. Now I want to read messages sent from that producer. My code

```
def main(args: Array[String]){
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
    val spark = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

    val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(spark, Seconds(5))
    val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(streamingContext
      , "localhost:2181"
      , "test-group"
      , Map("test" -> 1))
    kafkaStream.print
    streamingContext.start
    streamingContext.awaitTermination
  }
```

The dependencies I use

```
  <properties>
    <spark.version>1.6.2</spark.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

But every time I try to run it in idea I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.$conforms()Lscala/Predef$$less$colon$less;
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getSystemProperties(Utils.scala:1582)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.<init>(SparkConf.scala:53)
    at com.mypackage.KafkaConsumer$.main(KafkaConsumer.scala:10)
    at com.mypackage.KafkaConsumer.main(KafkaConsumer.scala)
```

Other questions here point to conflicts between dependencies.

I use scala 2.10.5 and spark 1.6.2. I tried them in other projects, they worked fine.

Line 10 in this case is `val sparkConf = new SparkConf()`

I try to run the app in the IDEA without packaging it.
What can be the reason for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an error with Scala version. You're are using different versions of scala in your code and dependencies.

You said you're using scala 2.10 but you import spark-XX_2.11 dependencies. Unify your scala version.